# Rails 3 routes for page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a page_controller with a few actions (dashboard, rules, contact). Each has a corresponding view. I don't know how to route it in Rails 3.

```
match 'page/:action' => 'page#:action'
```

The above doesn't work - what I would like is named routes like: page_path(:dashboard) or page_dashboard_path.

Any ideas?

- Jacob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write

```
get 'page/dashboard'
get 'page/rules'
get 'page/contact'
```

That will generate the correct named routes.

Note: you can always type `rake routes` to see which named routes are created.
For more info: see [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).